# Updating table column using radio button

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to update my column based on the selected radio button in my table data. I wanted to set `isApprove` column to true if radio button is selected. But I have the same name of radio how checked which radio button is selected so I can update my column `isApprove` to true.

View

```
<form class = "form-inline" method = "post" action = "{{ route ('document.pending', $list->id) }}">

    <div class = "radio">
        <label><input type = "radio" name = "status" value = "$list->id"> Approve</label>
    </div>

    <div class = "radio">
        <label><input type = "radio" name = "status" value = "$list->id"> Reject</label>
    </div>

</form>
```

As you can see here I passed the `$list->id` as the value in my radio button so it will determine which id is selected.

Controller

```
public function updateIsApprove($id)
{
    $document = Document::find($id);

    $document->isApprove = ;

    $document->save();
}
```

I'm stuck in this part don't have any idea how can I check which is selected.

Routes

```
Route::get('/documents/pending',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@documentsSentForApproval',
    'as' => 'document.pending',
]);

Route::post('/documents/pending/approve/{id}',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@updateIsApprove',
    'as' => 'document.pending',
]);
```

**UPDATE**

I followed what @SteD need to do and @Doom5 said.

View:

```
<form class = "form-inline" method = "post" action = "{{url('documents/pending/approve')}}">

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$list->id}}">

<div class = "radio">
    <label><input type = "radio" name = "status" value="approve"> Approve</label>
</div>

<div class = "radio">
    <label><input type = "radio" name = "status" value="reject"> Reject</label>
</div>

</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function updateIsApprove(Request $request, $document, $id)
{
    $document = Document::find($id);

    $document->isApprove = $request->status;

    $document->save();

    dd($request->all());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to pass 2 data over to your controller:

1. document ID
2. approve / reject (from radio box)

Blade

```
<form class = "form-inline" method = "post" action = "{{url('documents/pending/approve')}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$list->id}}">

    <div class = "radio">
        <label><input type = "radio" name = "status" value="approve"> Approve</label>
    </div>

    <div class = "radio">
        <label><input type = "radio" name = "status" value="reject"> Reject</label>
    </div>

</form>
```

Change your route to

```
Route::post('/documents/pending/approve',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@updateIsApprove',
    'as' => 'document.pending',
 ]);
```

You can retrieve the radiobox selected value by using `$request->status`

```
public function updateIsApprove(Request $request)
{
    $document = Document::find($request->id);

    $document->isApprove = $request->status;

    $document->save();
}
```

Comment: I already tried this solution but it says `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

Comment: Try <form class = "form-inline" method = "post" action = "{{url('documents/pending/approve')}}"> and see

Comment: Still getting the same error. I believed in your solution that I should not passed already the id in my action form. Right?

Comment: oops yeah, is $id the one you want to retrieve from the radio box?

Comment: I'm little bit confuse. Which part where I need to passed the values for Approve as `1` and Reject as `0`. Is my solution is right? I passed the id in the value?

Comment: You might want to add that `status` will contain the same value since that is what is set on the form.

Comment: @Francisunoxx You need to set the value attribute of your radio buttons to `1` and `0` for `true` and `false`, respectively. Or like @SteD did, use `approve` and `reject` as values.

Comment: @Francisunoxx code updated. the idea is you have to pass the doucment ID and status over to your controller, then you retrieve them using $request->{name_of_input}

Comment: @Doom5 @SteD Should I still need to passed the `Request` method in my controller? What I did is `public function updateIsApprove($document, $id)`

Comment: @Francisunoxx yes, change it to updateIsApprove(Request $request) , right inside the method, you can do a dd($request->all()) to look at the values.

Comment: @Francisunoxx You need it to access `status`.

Comment: @SteD I didn't show anything when I tried to die and dump. I still get a error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. I updated my post please see.

Comment: @Francisunoxx lets bring it to the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121889/updating-table-column-using-radio-button

Answer (score 0):

You have same name but the values are different. Then you can update based on the value of radio button.